# Compact decision tree vs non compact

Tags: cart

Suppose I have dataset and I run over it decision tree algorithm. If I get 2 types of decision trees one is compact (has few nodes and leaves) whereas the other one is not compact. What can be the reason for the difference between the two if they run over the same dataset?

Comment: Did you run the algorithm twice or is it an ensemble of trees, i.e. two trees on the same set?

Comment: Thanks Heinke, my case is for ensemble of trees, but I would like to relate although for a case of  the dataset for different algorithms and the same one number of times.

Comment: If it's an ensemble then the trees are probably trained on different random subsets of the data (bagging). This could cause one tree to be shallow because the underlying data can be separated more easily then to other. 

An other thing could be that the training process involved some random partitioning, like e.g. in C4.5 algorithm.

Could you add some more information? What algorithm did you use? Which data set? Which framework?

Comment: Thanks again, I would like to relate to the theoretical aspect of this case since I would like to generalize it to number of cases. If two algorithms yield for the for same dataset and for different datasets compact and non compact decision trees what can we say about the entropy or data distrubtion.